# error connecting to HBASE

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm getting below error while connecting to HBase in JAVA EAR Module however with console based application my code is working fine and I'm able to connect to HBASE via. Java program . Please let me know if any further information is needed .

1/19/15 16:45:22:087 IST] 0000004e HConnectionMa W org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionKey  Error obtaining current user, skipping username in HConnectionKey
[1/18/15 12:45:41:708 IST] 0000001f SystemErr     R java.io.IOException: failure to login
[1/18/15 12:45:41:708 IST] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:751)
[1/18/15 12:45:41:709 IST] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:703)
[1/18/15 12:45:41:709 IST] 0000001f SystemErr     R     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:605)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761449/hadoop-security-usergroupinformation-getloginuserusergroupinformation-java  -- same issue is mentioned here ... any resolution ?

Comment: Check if you have the EAR container ran under a different user than the one you log in with in the console.

Comment: can you please describe how to check this ? many thanks !!

Comment: Use ps command to get user id

Comment: this seems to java issue . Is there any way I can check what user name JAAS is using ?

Comment: http://rajesh-hadoop.blogspot.in/2013/01/hadoop-103-api-frequently-faced-problems.html - it says #7 - while connecting hbase through webservice (check for the build path all required dll are there or not, if it works throught code) - please advice if any one has any suggestion .

Comment: Did you run ps command on the machine you are running EAR? What is user id of the process?

Comment: Actually I'm on window platform and ps is for window command but just fyi , I'm running the EAR from the same machine where i'm running java program ...

Comment: this turnout to be known issue with web-sphere and hadoop integration . I run the same code in Apache Server and it worked fine ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this turnout to be known issue with web-sphere and hadoop integration . I run the same code in Apache Server and it worked fine ....